# Not receiving any errors on PDO MySQL Update Query but query does not work

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

When I run this query, it runs fine with no errors. Except, it's not updating the query.

I've checked to make sure the `$createdForm_id` exists in the rows of my table, there are values in `$document_id`, and values in `$time_saved`.

Could anyone help me out to see what I am doing wrong here?

```
//new database
 $opt = array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
 try { $dbh_forms = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=website_data", "root", "123", $opt); }
 catch(PDOException $e) { echo $e->getMessage(); }

$update_data = $dbh_forms->prepare("UPDATE form_data SET document_id = :document_id AND time_saved = :time_saved WHERE id = :id");
$update_data->execute(array(':document_id' => $document_id, ':time_saved' => $time, ':id' => $createdForm_id));
```

Comment: `SET field=value, field=value` no AND. Yes your query runs fine.. but it doesn't update anything (when using PDO or otherwise)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have an 'and' in your query that does not belong there. Change this:

`$update_data = $dbh_forms->prepare("UPDATE form_data SET document_id = :document_id AND time_saved = :time_saved WHERE id = :id");`

To this by removing the and and adding a comma:
`$update_data = $dbh_forms->prepare("UPDATE form_data SET document_id = :document_id, time_saved = :time_saved WHERE id = :id");`

Comment: Hmm. Why would someone down vote a 100% correct answer?